# creating xls file in web server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an xls document using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` but it's not working in IIS7.

I am getting the error message below

> Microsoft Office Excel cannot open or save any more documents because
>   there is not enough available memory or disk space. • To make more
>   memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need. • To
>   free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are
>   saving to.

Is there any other free tool or option that we can use to create xls in web server?

Comment: ah how much free space does you hardrive have ? and in terms of memory ?

Comment: Check that link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2c753037-4600-4a4f-abd7-d228e2f20a38/2146827284microsoft-excel-cannot-open-or-save-any-more-documents-because-there-is-not-enough

Comment: i have tried but still facing same issue.so i want to go with other implementation.pls let me know easy way to create xsl and save it  to client pc or server

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a good idea to use office interop API on a server as described in this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-gb).

For free tools you could look at [ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) and [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) that seems to be popular but I never used it. The other option would be to use the [OOXML SDK 2.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). With this you can create only Xlsx files and has a learning curve.

For more info have look a this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp) that, although it is closed, contains probably all the info you need.